# does lib property overwrite target property in tsconfig.json

Tags: javascript, json, typescript

I'm new to typescript, just a question on lib property and target property 
below is the tsconfig.json File:

```
{
 "compilerOptions": {
 "target": "es5",
 "outDir": "./dist",
 "rootDir": "./src",
 "noEmitOnError": true,
 }
}
```

```
//index.ts
console.log("Hello World");
```

so it works perfectly,

but then I want to the ES6 Map() so I change configuare file to :

```
{
 "compilerOptions": {
 "target": "es5",
 "outDir": "./dist",
 "rootDir": "./src",
 "noEmitOnError": true,
 "lib": ["es6"]
 }
}
```

then I got an error:

> cannot find name 'console'

Below is my question

Q1-isn't that es5, es6 include DOM API already?

Q2-if es5 and es6 doesn't includes DOM API, how come it work for the first time without lib property?

Answer (score 3):

TypeScript has default values for `lib` based on the `target` you've set.

They are documented on the [compiler options page](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html)
<sub>(unfortunately I can't directly link to it, search `--lib` to jump to it)</sub>

- **ES5**: `DOM`, `ES5`, `ScriptHost`
- **ES6**: `DOM`, `ES6`, `DOM.Iterable`, `ScriptHost`

---

So as the other answer says, if you specify `lib` manually you have to make sure to include things from the defaults you need as well:

```
"lib": ["dom", "es6"]
```

---

If you're wondering what some of these libraries include take a look at the file itself on the [TypeScript repo in the `lib` folder](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/tree/master/lib). For example `ScriptHost` is [`lib.scripthost.d.ts`](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/lib/lib.scripthost.d.ts)

Answer (score 1):

Add the `dom` library as well - see [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What's-new-in-TypeScript#including-built-in-type-declarations-with---lib) for other libraries:

```
"lib": ["dom", "es6"]
```

Comment: but why it still worked for the first time when there is no "lib" property in the configuration file at all?

Comment: Probably a default value.